# using yamlFile for podSpec in jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

Team, am trying to use [yamlFile](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-declarative-pipeline)

paths:

```
release/docs.jenkinsfile
release/pod.yaml
```

however, i am getting this error. not sure what syntax am missing below is pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
        cloud 'sc-ipp'
        yamlFile 'pod.yaml'
        retries 2
    }
  }
```

errror

```
11:01:32  org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
11:01:32  Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node, dockerNode
11:01:32    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:90)
11:01:32    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
11:01:32    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
11:01:32    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
11:01:32    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
11:01:32    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
11:01:32    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
11:01:32    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
11:01:32  
11:01:32  [Pipeline] }
11:01:32  [Pipeline] // stage
11:01:32  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
11:01:32  ERROR: /var/jenkins/workspace/release/docs@script/8915c9c09bcd269f5b16278273fe6037a39d8fc1e50cb41e4afd83b6b95343c6/pod.yaml not found
11:01:32  Finished: FAILURE
```

my jenkinsfile and pod are both in same location.

Comment: the error clearly saying `pod.yaml not found`. jenkins file could be on master, but pipeline executed on agent.

Comment: to test path: i specified a dumy path and for that it clearly stated pod.yaml not in workspace. so it is reading it
`references a file that is not inside /var/jenkins/workspace/release`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember that path is relative to the workspace root, not to the Jenkinsfile.

So the following should work:

```java
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
        cloud 'sc-ipp'
        yamlFile 'release/pod.yaml'
        retries 2
    }
}
```